# How can I include text from a cell within a COUNTIF function in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am using sheets to mark quiz responses. I am trying to display a 1 if the answer contains a certain string (therefore, is correct).

For example, COUNTIF(d2, "*serbia"). 
So, if D2 contains this text, display a 1.

However, I want to get the text "serbia" (for example) from another cell. So a separate cell just contains "serbia" and I refer to that cell in the COUNTIF function.

So, if D2 contains the text from C19, display a 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` to create the criterion you need. Since the given answer may not *end* with the correct answer, I would add another `*` as well:

```
=COUNTIF(D2,"*"&C19&"*")
```

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LUEamicB60u-QOBZWmwjESh8va_nstPe_rURUFY4Sqs/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]